# Including sound files in a pygame script using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller, pong

I am new to programming, so I made myself the challenge to create Pong, and so I did. Now I want to share it with a couple of friends, so I decided to try using pyinstaller (have tried cx_Freeze).
In this Pong game I have 3 sound effects, located in the folder "sfx". So I've looked into including files using pyinstaller, so my .spec file says:

```
added_files = [
        ('E:\Game Development Stuff\Python 3\Games\Pong\sfx\hitOutline.ogg', 'sfx'),
        ('E:\Game Development Stuff\Python 3\Games\Pong\sfx\hitPaddle.ogg', 'sfx'),
        ('E:\Game Development Stuff\Python 3\Games\Pong\sfx/score.ogg', 'sfx')
        ]

a = Analysis(['pong.py'],
         pathex=['E:\\Game Development Stuff\\Python 3\\Games\\Pong'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=added_files,
```

and in the Pong program itself, I use this code to get the path:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    return os.path.join(relative)

fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))


hitPaddle = resource_path(os.path.join(fileDir, "sfx", "hitPaddle.ogg"))
hitOutline = resource_path(os.path.join(fileDir, "sfx", "hitOutline.ogg"))
score = resource_path(os.path.join(fileDir, "sfx", "score.ogg"))

hitPaddleSound=pygame.mixer.Sound(hitPaddle)
hitOutlineSound=pygame.mixer.Sound(hitOutline)
scoreSound=pygame.mixer.Sound(score)
```

So I make the exe file using pyinstaller (with the command pyinstaller pong.spec)
but when I open the pong.exe file the command window says:

```
Traceback "<string>", Unable to open file 'E:\\Game Development Stuff\\Python 3\\Games\\Pong\\dist\\pong\\sfx\\hitPaddle.ogg'
```

but in that exact same path is hitPaddle.ogg. 
It seems to me that pygame isn't able to found it for some weird reason?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is in this line. You are not refrencing the files correctly. You wrote:

```
hitPaddle = resource_path(os.path.join(fileDir, "sfx", "hitPaddle.ogg"))
```

Instead you should of just:

```
hitpaddle = resource_path("sfx\hitPaddle.ogg")
```

This is because when you added the files in the spec file, you stated that they should be in "*root\sfx*" folder. When the .exe is run in onefile mode, all files are actually located in a temp folder called MEIXXXX, with XXXX being some integers. When you run the .exe, if you open this folder you should be able to see your files there.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Sadly I wasn't able to fix the problem with your solution. It gives me the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for me after struggling with the same issue for hours. Conclusions:

The problem is not in not being able to find it, then it would say something with 'could not find'. It is really an issue with opening the file. Somehow, the .ogg format is giving issues. I changed all my .ogg files to .wav files and my game is running without problems now as executable.

I have no idea why though, because two weeks ago for a previous version I did manage to make a working .exe with the exact same .ogg files. And I don't see how the changes I made should have any effect on this. Anyway, it works now, and perhaps this can also solve this problem for others.